# IntelliJ missing Android SDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

[image]

[image]

Please see the pictures above

When I click on Android in IntelliJ, this message appears:

> Your Android SDK is missing. out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 24.0.2 or later.
>   You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs

So I click Java at the top and then click  to specify the path to java 9.0. But I still have problems, so I went into the Android studio and selected Android SDK to install several SDKs including 8.0. But still Android SDK is missing. Why is IntelliJ not finding the Android SDK? Do I need to set environment variables?

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ for Android? You should be using Android Studio

Comment: I installed the Android studio.

Comment: Yet you don't use it. Check the top-left corner of the project wizard - it's the IntelliJ logo. Android Studio has the Android Studio logo there, meaning you're creating the project in IntelliJ. Try it in Android Studio and see if it changes anything

Comment: It has been resolved. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is IntelliJ not finding the Android SDK?

You need to add it. In Android studio, it gets automatically added when you install it. But IntelliJ IDEA will not know where it is. Go to *File > Project Structure > "SDKs" under "Platform Settings"*. Click the plus sign at the top and select "Android SDK". You'll need to select the SDK from its installation location (you want to navigate to the `Android/sdk` directory).

[image]

That said... you're probably better off using Android Studio to do your Android development until you become a bit more experienced with the IDE unless there is a compelling reason you need to use IntelliJ IDEA (such as support for an additional language).

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. The location of the SDK is not in the path. So, I went directly to the Windows folder. Finally, I found the SDK in the hidden folder, and I copied and pasted that path.